# how can I make custom auto generated IDs for documents in firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For my project I need ids that can be easily shared, so firestores default auto generated ids won't work.
I am looking for a way to auto generate id like `8329423` that would be incremented or randomly chosen in range 0 to 9999999.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include **your code** in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore's auto-ID fields are designed to statistically guarantee that no two clients will ever generate the same value. This is why they're as long as they are: it's to ensure there is enough randomness (entropy) in them.

This allows Firestore to determine these keys completely client-side without needing to look up on the server whether the key it generated was already generated on another client before. And this in turn has these main benefits:

1. Since the keys are generated client-side, they can also be generated when the client is not connected to any server.
2. Since the keys are generated client-side, there is no need for a roundtrip to the server to generate a new key. This significantly speeds up the process.
3. Since the keys are generated client-side, there is no contention between clients generating keys. Each client just generates keys as needed.

If these benefits are important to your use-case, then you should strongly consider whether you're likely to create a better unique ID than Firestore already does. For example, Firestore's IDs have 62^20 unique values, which is why they're statistically guaranteed to never generate the same value over a very long period of time. Your proposed range of 0 - 9999999 has 1 million unique values, which is much more likely to generate duplicate.

If you really want this scheme for IDs, you will need to store the IDs that you've already given out on the server (likely in Firestore), so that you can check against it when generating a new key. A very common way to do this is to keep a counter of the last ID you've already handed out in a document. To generate a new unique ID, you:

1. Read the latest counter value from the document.
2. Increment the counter.
3. Write the updated counter value to the document.
4. Use the updated counter value in your code.

Since this read-update-write happens from multiple clients, you will need to use a transaction for it. Also note that the clients now are coordinating the key-generation, so you're going to experience throughput limits on the number of keys you can generate.