# Generating same document id after delete it

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I deleted for example this document `oLgPsmKIDNjcpBdJEyq0` can be regenerating in future?

Also could I generate random id for field name such as documents?

Comment: If by "If I deleted for example this document oLgPsmKIDNjcpBdJEyq0 can be regenerating in future?" you ask if you can reuse the id of a doc after having deleted it the answer is yes. For "could I generate random id for field name such as documents": can you clarify what you exactly mean. Maybe with an example.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec About first point I was mean can the system regeneration same id who deleted already ( Not by me )

Comment: @RenaudTarnec For example If I told server create random document name, Does the server will create same id who deleted? ( Small possibility, but can it happen? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773646/how-can-i-make-custom-auto-generated-ids-for-documents-in-firestore/55774299#55774299):

> Firestore's auto-ID fields are designed to statistically guarantee
> that no two clients will ever generate the same value.

So, to answer "can the system regeneration same id who deleted already" => No, if you use the [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) method or the [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method without passing a path, Firestore will not generate twice the same ID. If you want to reuse it you should save it somewhere.

*(I actually cannot mark the question as duplicate since I had already voted to close it for clarification)*

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Never allow auto ID to regenerate it. However if a user need some identity for future use, he can use a user define id within the document. This id can be numeric, string, uuid etc. type